# Extending / Customizing codebehind file

Tags: acumatica

Is there a method to extend/modify the code behind file with the Acumatica customization manager?

For example, the Page_Init sets the PopupHeight/Width for a page.    If this value needs to be modified to make the window larger/smaller or add some additional hooks and create a Page_Load method, can this be done from the customization manager?

Seeing how these are partial classes, can the class be extended from a Extension file?

Comment: not sure about a way. for height/width we just set the values in the aspx. if done right the sizes of even pop up panels will auto adjust with visible fields changing. I am guessing you are looking for something a little more than that tho.